# Encode or escape UTF-8 characters in Windows Console output

Tags: php, csv, command-line, pdo

Running a php script that imports a csv datafile and saves it to MySQL. Works fine when calling the script from a browser. Webserver is Apache on a Windows machine.

But running the same php script on same datafile from the command line via a windows 7 batch file will not handle the characters in the datafile such as apostrophes and trademark symbols. 
Getting errors: Incorrect string value \xA2 for column.., Incorrect string value \xE9 for column..

Details:
PHP 5.5.10. Apache 2.4.7 on Windows 7. MySql 5.5.11.

CSV data example of a field that fails:

,,"testing the description's field trademark symbol™ that fails",,

relevant code in script:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx;charset=utf8', 'xxxx', 'xxxx',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

$handle = @fopen(URL_DATAFEED, "r"); 

//load the csv file into an array
while (! feof($handle)) {
    $arrData[] =  fgetcsv($handle);
}
$stmtInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (ITEM,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (:ITEM,:DESCRIPTION)");
$stmtInsert->execute(<<arrayWithData>>);
```

batch file contents:

```
@ECHO off
chcp 65001
php "scriptname.php"
pause
```

Command window font has been changed to Lucida console.
But there's something with the php shell command line that doesn't process the data the same as apache??

Thanks very much.

Comment: How do you read the file?

Comment: Using fopen. 
$handle = @fopen(URL_DATAFEED, "r");

Comment: Try calling setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en.UTF8'); at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I've learned that when $str contains a trademark symbol,  mb_check_encoding($str,"UTF-8") returns true when run from the web, but false when run from the command line. But php from command line uses same php.ini file. php -i says loaded configuration file c:\php\php.ini

Comment: Another thing that might bite you is the text/byte mode flag for fopen on windows. This is also present in PHP. It opens files in text mode by default. That can cause all sorts of problems. Try fopen(URL_DATAFEED, "rb");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that using strtoupper() on the datafield containing a trademark symbol was causing the insert problem when running php from a windows 7 batch file. I believe this is because "alphabetic conversion is determined by the current locale" (per the PHP manual), and my Windows 7 locale must not be UTF-8. While Apache is set to UTF-8.

If you need to convert a string with symbols to uppercase, use
mb_strtoupper($string,'UTF-8').

Thank you for the above comments that got me on the right track!